# Why do Akdamut, Reshuyot on Simchat Torah and Yom Tov kiddush use the same tune?

Tags: yom-tov, music, kiddush, shavuos, simchat-torah

[The tune used for Yom Tov Kiddush throughout the year by most Ashkenazim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20199/5275) is almost exactly like the tune used for *Akdamut* - the Aramaic poem recited in many Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard synagogues just prior to reading the Torah on the 1st day of Shavu'ot, and the "reshuyot" for Chatanei Torah and Breishit on Simchat Torah (Thanks to DoubleAA for pointing tout the Reshuyot).

Is there any relationship between kiddush and these other items that historically have them use the same tunes?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no "official tune" for Kiddush. Also, the tune that I use for Akdamus is (I think) quite different than any Kiddush I've heard.

Comment: I do know the similarity between Akdamut, Kiddush Hagim and Reshuyot Hatanim, but have never heard of a logical link. Perhaps it's just that it fits (more or less).

Comment: @Epicentre Could be. To me, I think there is another reason. I don't think that these tunes or modes are chosen randomly. It's not like singing Lecha Dodi to "Essa Einai".

Comment: In all the Ashkenazi shuls I have attended, Akdomus is sung to the tune recorded for [here](https://www.kayj.net/en/nusach) see Yomim Tovim, Shovu'os, Kaddish Tiskabal which is the same tune for Akdomus.